# How to group items by path (graph structure) and leave only those with highest score using t-sql?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, graph

I have a table with records and their scores (table 'Offers'):

```
OfferId     OfferScore
----------- -----------
1           1
2           20
3           3
4           4
5           5
6           6
7           7
8           8
```

These records might be related. All relations are stored in the table 'OffersRelation':

```
OfferId1    OfferId2
----------- -----------
1           2
1           3
1           4
1           5
2           3
3           5
7           8
```

I want to remove all related Ids (within the group) from table Offers and leave only ones with the highest score.

In my case :

Offers with Ids: 1,2,3,4,5 are related ("group") and the offer with id:2 has the highest score:20 so I want to remove ids: 1,3,4,5 and leave only the one with id:2 from this "group".

Offer with Id:6  doesn't have any related items (no relations in the table OffersRelations) so it stays in the table Offers.

Offers with Ids:7,8 are related and Offer with id:8 has higher score than 7 so i want to remove the offer with id:7 and leave the offer with id:8 from this "group".

Expected result in the table Offers:

```
OfferId     OfferScore
----------- -----------
2           20
6           6
8           8
```

### How to do it in t-sql?

Data from examples:

```
drop table if exists dbo.Offers
drop table if exists dbo.OffersRelation
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Offers](
    [OfferId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [OfferScore] [int] NOT NULL
) 
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[OffersRelation](
    [OfferId1] [int] NOT NULL,
    [OfferId2] [int] NOT NULL
) 
GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Offers]
           ([OfferId],[OfferScore])
     VALUES (1,1),(2,20),(3,3),(4,4),(5,5),(6,6),(7,7),(8,8)


INSERT INTO [dbo].[OffersRelation]
           ([OfferId1]
           ,[OfferId2])
     VALUES
            (1,2),
            (1,3),
            (1,4),
            (1,5),
            (2,3),
            (3,5),
            (7,8)
```

Comment: I don't get why you would remove Id 1 from table1. What's the relation between table1 and table2?

Comment: @MattiaNocerino in table1 i have all items (ads with cars on sale), in table2 i have a result of a 'duplicate' detection scan. It means that we might have 5 different offers but all of them display the same car on sale so i want to pick the most complete (highest score) and remove the others.

Comment: This smells like bad design to me, but i may be wrong. Why do you have 2 different tables to store the same thing? Wouldn't be better something like a `car` table and an `ads` table? That way it would be even easier to get the highest score for the same car

Comment: @MattiaNocerino the design is not important here. it's just an example to show the problem

Answer (score 3):

I have completely redone my answer (based on the additional information you provided in your question).

You indicated that you tried recursion and it was too slow on a large set of data.  I've created a cursor based solution that works on your test data, but I'm wondering if it gives you the correct answer on your production data.  With such a small set of test data, it's difficult to spot flaws in my logic.

Can you give it a try and let me know if I'm any closer to a proper solution?

```
DECLARE @OfferId INT
DECLARE @OffersToDelete TABLE (id INT)

--Declare cursor for all Offers
DECLARE _CURSOR CURSOR LOCAL FORWARD_ONLY STATIC READ_ONLY
FOR
SELECT [o].offerid
FROM Offers [o]
ORDER BY [o].OfferId

OPEN _CURSOR

FETCH NEXT
FROM _CURSOR
INTO @OfferId

DECLARE @Related TABLE (OfferId INT)

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    --For each Offer, initialize @Related table
    DELETE
    FROM @Related

    --Insert into @Related the Offerid that we are currently processing
    INSERT INTO @Related
    SELECT [or].OfferId2
    FROM OffersRelation [or]
    WHERE [or].OfferId1 = @OfferId

    --Now, loop through all offers related to the one we're processing
    --When @@ROWCOUNT = 0, you have processed all related rows and need
    --to break out of the while loop
    WHILE 1 = 1
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @Related
        SELECT [or].OfferId2
        FROM OffersRelation [or]
        JOIN @Related [r]
            ON [r].OfferId = [or].OfferId1
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT *
                FROM @Related
                WHERE OfferId = [or].OfferId2
                )
            AND [r].OfferId <> @OfferId

        IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
            BREAK;
    END;

    --With all related rows, including the offer we're processing,
    --add a row number ordered by OfferScore desc and insert all rows
    --not = 1 into the @OffersToDelete table
    WITH OfferAndRelated
    AS (
        SELECT Offerid
            ,offerscore
        FROM offers
        WHERE offerid = @OfferId

        UNION

        SELECT [o].offerid
            ,[o].offerscore
        FROM @Related [r]
        JOIN Offers [o]
            ON [o].OfferId = [r].OfferId
        )
        ,OfferAndRelatedWithRowNumber
    AS (
        SELECT *
            ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                ORDER BY OfferScore DESC
                ) AS rn
        FROM OfferAndRelated
        )
    INSERT INTO @OffersToDelete
    SELECT OfferId
    FROM OfferAndRelatedWithRowNumber
    WHERE rn <> 1

    --  SELECT *
    --  FROM @Related
    FETCH NEXT
    FROM _CURSOR
    INTO @OfferId
END

CLOSE _CURSOR

DEALLOCATE _CURSOR

--Delete from Offers where the OfferId is on the @OffersToDelete table
DELETE [o]
FROM Offers [o]
JOIN @OffersToDelete otd
    ON otd.id = [o].OfferId

SELECT *
FROM Offers
```

---

```
| OfferId | OfferScore |
|---------|------------|
| 2       | 20         |
| 6       | 6          |
| 8       | 8          |
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83744/discussion-between-free4ride-and-scott-hodgin).

Answer (score 3):

I worked up a solution for SQL 2017 using graph tables but it's a bit unwieldy.  Transitive closure still has to done with a loop as at this version (happy to be corrected).  SQL Server 2019 promises to bring transitive closure (as per [here](https://sqlservervnexteap.azurewebsites.net/)) but for now try this:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #tmpOffers
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #tmpOffersRelation
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.Offers
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.isRelatedTo
GO

CREATE TABLE #tmpOffers (
    OfferId         INT PRIMARY KEY,
    OfferScore      INT NOT NULL
)
GO

CREATE TABLE #tmpOffersRelation (
    OfferId1    INT NOT NULL,
    OfferId2    INT NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY ( OfferId1, OfferId2 )
)
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.Offers (
    OfferId         INT PRIMARY KEY,
    OfferScore      INT NOT NULL
    ) AS NODE


CREATE TABLE dbo.isRelatedTo AS EDGE;
GO

INSERT INTO #tmpOffers
VALUES
    ( 1, 1  ),
    ( 2, 20 ),
    ( 3, 3  ),
    ( 4, 4  ),
    ( 5, 5  ),
    ( 6, 6  ),
    ( 7, 7  ),
    ( 8, 8  )

INSERT INTO #tmpOffersRelation 
VALUES
    ( 1, 2 ), 
    ( 1, 3 ), 
    ( 1, 4 ), 
    ( 1, 5 ), 
    ( 2, 3 ), 
    ( 3, 5 ), 
    ( 7, 8 )
GO


INSERT INTO dbo.Offers ( OfferId, OfferScore )
SELECT OfferId, OfferScore
FROM #tmpOffers

INSERT INTO dbo.isRelatedTo ( $from_id, $to_id )
SELECT o1.$node_id, o2.$node_id
FROM #tmpOffersRelation o
    INNER JOIN dbo.Offers o1 ON o.OfferId1 = o1.OfferId
    INNER JOIN dbo.Offers o2 ON o.OfferId2 = o2.OfferId
GO

-- Run match queries
SELECT FORMATMESSAGE( 'Offer %i is related to Offer %i with scores of %i and %i.', o1.OfferId, o2.OfferId, o1.OfferScore, o2.OfferScore )
FROM dbo.Offers o1, dbo.isRelatedTo isRelatedTo, dbo.Offers o2
WHERE MATCH ( o1-(isRelatedTo)->o2 );
GO

/*
OfferId     OfferScore
2           20
6           6
8           8
*/

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS dbo.utf_tc
GO

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.utf_tc ( @OfferId INT ) 
RETURNS @var TABLE
(
    OfferId     INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED,
    OfferScore  INT NOT NULL,
    xlevel      INT NOT NULL, 

    UNIQUE CLUSTERED( xlevel, OfferId )
)
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @xlevel INT = 0

    -- Get first node
    INSERT INTO @var( OfferId, OfferScore, xlevel )
    SELECT OfferId, OfferScore, @xlevel 
    FROM dbo.Offers
    WHERE OfferId = @OfferId


    -- Loop thru children
    WHILE @@rowcount > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @xlevel += 1

        -- Get children
        INSERT INTO @var( OfferId, OfferScore, xlevel )
        SELECT DISTINCT Offers2.OfferId, Offers2.OfferScore, @xlevel
        FROM @var AS tc, dbo.Offers Offers1, dbo.isRelatedTo isRelatedTo, dbo.Offers Offers2
        WHERE tc.OfferId = Offers1.OfferId
          AND MATCH ( Offers1-(isRelatedTo)->Offers2 )
          AND tc.xlevel = @xlevel - 1
          AND NOT EXISTS (  -- id does not already exist
            SELECT *
            FROM @var
            WHERE OfferId = Offers2.OfferId
            )

    END

    RETURN
END
GO


;WITH cte AS (
SELECT o.OfferId AS chainId, f.OfferId, f.OfferScore, f.xlevel
FROM dbo.Offers o
    CROSS APPLY dbo.utf_tc( o.OfferId ) f
), cte2 AS (
SELECT c.OfferId, c.OfferScore, RANK() OVER( PARTITION BY c.chainId ORDER BY c.OfferScore DESC ) AS xrank
FROM cte c
    INNER JOIN
    ( -- Get the min chainid per offerId
    SELECT offerId, MIN(chainId) AS chainId
    FROM cte c2
    GROUP BY offerId
    ) x ON c.chainId = x.chainId  
        AND c.offerId = x.OfferId
)
SELECT OfferId, OfferScore
FROM cte2
WHERE xrank = 1
ORDER BY xrank
```

My results:

[image: My results]

**Update after comments from OP**

Comment:
This is great but it fails with 1 case:Try "INSERT INTO #tmpOffers VALUES (1,1),(2,4),(3,3),(4,2) INSERT INTO #tmpOffersRelation VALUES (1,2),(3,4),(2,4)" .It returns two elements: 2 and 3, It should return only one element: 2 with score 4 because 3 is connected with 4 and 4 is connected with 2. But what is strange in your solution, if you swap relation (3,4) with (4,3) the solution works.... – free4ride 13 hours ago

My reply:
The way I've implemented the rules, the relationships are one-directional, so with the original data there are three chains: 1 > 2 > 3 > 5 and 6 and 7 > 8, thus 3 records returned.  It looks like this:

[image: first dataset]

With your second set of sample data (and with the way I have implemented the rules) there are two chains: 1 > 2 > 4 and 3 > 4, ie both chains end in 4.  It looks like this:

[image: second dataset]

Try thinking about your rules visually and how you want them implemented.  It would in theory be possible to make the relationships bi-directional but now you're learning all about graph in SQL I'll leave it as an exercise for the reader!

PS If you've got a simple way to test out that 200k dataset I would like to trial it as it's also possible to index graph tables.